# Filter array of nested objects based on nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, nested-object

I am looking to filter an array based on a value in a nested object.

My code goes as follows to find the products containing the "inventory_type" of "Credit" but I get an error saying some is not a function and would need some guidance as to the best approach to search this deep in an array

```js
let object = [{
  "summary": [{
    "count": 2,
    "inventory_region": "England & Wales",
    "inventory_type": "Add-on"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "inventory_region": "England & Wales",
    "inventory_type": "Credit"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "inventory_region": "England & Wales",
    "inventory_type": "Social-boost"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "inventory_region": "Scotland",
    "inventory_type": "Add-on"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "inventory_region": "Scotland",
    "inventory_type": "Credit"
  }],
  "products": [{
    "count": 2,
    "display_label_short": "14 Day Add On E&W",
    "inventory_region": "England & Wales",
    "display_label": "14 Day Add On E&W",
    "inventory_type": "Add-on"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "display_label_short": "Standard 28 Day Listing E&W",
    "inventory_region": "England & Wales",
    "display_label": "Standard 28 Day Listing E&W",
    "inventory_type": "Credit"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "display_label_short": "14 Day Boost E&W",
    "inventory_region": "England & Wales",
    "display_label": "14 Day Boost E&W",
    "inventory_type": "Social-boost"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "display_label_short": "14 Day Add On SCO",
    "inventory_region": "Scotland",
    "display_label": "14 Day Add On SCO",
    "inventory_type": "Add-on"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "display_label_short": "Standard 28 Day Listing SCO",
    "inventory_region": "Scotland",
    "display_label": "Standard 28 Day Listing SCO",
    "inventory_type": "Credit"
  }],
  "company_id": 2876909,
  "company_name": "Automated Testing"
}]


let newArr = object.map(objects => {
  return objects.products.filter(products => {
    products.some(product => product.inventory_type === 'Credit')
  })
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "inner products" is not an array but just one product

```js
 let object = [{ "summary": [{ "count": 2, "inventory_region": "England & Wales", "inventory_type": "Add-on" }, { "count": 2, "inventory_region": "England & Wales", "inventory_type": "Credit" }, { "count": 2, "inventory_region": "England & Wales", "inventory_type": "Social-boost" }, { "count": 2, "inventory_region": "Scotland", "inventory_type": "Add-on" }, { "count": 2, "inventory_region": "Scotland", "inventory_type": "Credit" }], "products": [{ "count": 2, "display_label_short": "14 Day Add On E&W", "inventory_region": "England & Wales", "display_label": "14 Day Add On E&W", "inventory_type": "Add-on" }, { "count": 2, "display_label_short": "Standard 28 Day Listing E&W", "inventory_region": "England & Wales", "display_label": "Standard 28 Day Listing E&W", "inventory_type": "Credit" }, { "count": 2, "display_label_short": "14 Day Boost E&W", "inventory_region": "England & Wales", "display_label": "14 Day Boost E&W", "inventory_type": "Social-boost" }, { "count": 2, "display_label_short": "14 Day Add On SCO", "inventory_region": "Scotland", "display_label": "14 Day Add On SCO", "inventory_type": "Add-on" }, { "count": 2, "display_label_short": "Standard 28 Day Listing SCO", "inventory_region": "Scotland", "display_label": "Standard 28 Day Listing SCO", "inventory_type": "Credit" }], "company_id": 2876909, "company_name": "Automated Testing" }] 

let newArr = object.map(objects => objects.products.filter(product =>
  product.inventory_type === 'Credit'
))

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It returns what I expect. Unfortunately it is an endpoint returning the data in this way.

Comment: What does that mean? I did not change the data in any way

Comment: sorry it means I did not realise the inner products was not an array and I was trying to dig too deep. You have pointed out the error in my code and helped me resolve the question

Comment: "products" is an array, but `filter(products` << this is one product

Comment: yip makes perfect sense when you read it out loud. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are going one too deep on your filtering:

```js
let object = [{
  "summary": [{
    "count": 2,
    "inventory_region": "England & Wales",
    "inventory_type": "Add-on"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "inventory_region": "England & Wales",
    "inventory_type": "Credit"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "inventory_region": "England & Wales",
    "inventory_type": "Social-boost"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "inventory_region": "Scotland",
    "inventory_type": "Add-on"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "inventory_region": "Scotland",
    "inventory_type": "Credit"
  }],
  "products": [{
    "count": 2,
    "display_label_short": "14 Day Add On E&W",
    "inventory_region": "England & Wales",
    "display_label": "14 Day Add On E&W",
    "inventory_type": "Add-on"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "display_label_short": "Standard 28 Day Listing E&W",
    "inventory_region": "England & Wales",
    "display_label": "Standard 28 Day Listing E&W",
    "inventory_type": "Credit"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "display_label_short": "14 Day Boost E&W",
    "inventory_region": "England & Wales",
    "display_label": "14 Day Boost E&W",
    "inventory_type": "Social-boost"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "display_label_short": "14 Day Add On SCO",
    "inventory_region": "Scotland",
    "display_label": "14 Day Add On SCO",
    "inventory_type": "Add-on"
  }, {
    "count": 2,
    "display_label_short": "Standard 28 Day Listing SCO",
    "inventory_region": "Scotland",
    "display_label": "Standard 28 Day Listing SCO",
    "inventory_type": "Credit"
  }],
  "company_id": 2876909,
  "company_name": "Automated Testing"
}]


let newArr = object.map(objects => {
  return objects.products.filter(product => (product.inventory_type === 'Credit'))
})

console.log(newArr)
```